# Python write file function creates an extra blank line?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that writes a contact to an database, and then its managed with other functions (The whole program will be listed as a GitHub link at the end of the post), then written back to the file with a `write_db_to_file` function. However, I have the `db` dictionary built with my `build_db` function, which, if there's any extra line or empty space, or anything that doesn't belong, then the program breaks on start-up as it's not finding what it's looking for in the file (`ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`)

Here is the `build_db` function:

```
def build_db(path, mode=0):
    if mode == 0:
        
        db = {}
        if os.path.exists('contacts.txt') == False:
            with open('contacts.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write('CONTACT: DEV')
                f.write('\n    First Name: FELIX')
                f.write('\n    Last Name: MARTIN')
                f.write('\n    Number: N/A')
                f.write('\n    Address: N/A')
            print("Please re-run the program.")
            quit()
        else:
            #while opening contacts.txt as f
            with open(path) as f:
                for line in f:
                    #strip the file and split each line from the 'CATEGORY' and the 'VALUE'
                    #e.g. split 'CONTACT: YOU' to 'CONTACT', 'YOU'
                    category, value = map(str.strip, line.split(":"))
                    #if the stripped line is the CONTACT line
                    if category == "CONTACT":
                        #set the current contact to start a new dictionary with the value of the contact
                        cur_contact = value
                        db[value] = {}
                    #if the stripped line is the data within the CONTACT line
                    else:
                        #set the previously set dictionarys data with another dictionary
                        db.get(cur_contact, {})[category] = value
            #return the database when its called
            return db
    #unless debug mode is set to 1
    
    else:
        #do everything as before, except print data for debugging
        db = {}
        with open(path) as f:
            for line in f:
                category, value = map(str.strip, line.split(":"))
                mapDebug = map(str.strip, line.split(":"))
                print("Printing mapDebug\n")
                print(mapDebug)
                print("Printing category, value\n") 
                print(category, value)
                if category == "CONTACT":
                    cur_contact = value
                    db[value] = {}
                    print("Printing db[value]\n")
                    print(db[value])
                else:
                    print("Printing db.get(cur_contact, {})[category]\n")
                    print(db.get(cur_contact, {})[category])
                    db.get(cur_contact, {})[category] = value
        print(db)
        return db        
#finally, build the database off of the local contacts.txt file
db = build_db("contacts.txt")
```

Here is the `write_db_to_file` function:

```
   def write_db_to_file(self, db, out_path):
        with open(out_path, 'w+') as outf:
            #for each contact
            for contact_name in db:
                #write the values of each in the correct format
                outf.write(self.read_contact(db, contact_name.upper()))
            #DEBUG/NOT WORKING: clear any blank lines
            for line in outf:
                if not line.isspace():
                    outf.write(line)
        self.contact_manager(db)
```

Let's say the `contacts.txt` is as follows:

```
CONTACT: DEV
    First Name: FELIX
    Last Name: MARTIN
    Number: N/A
    Address: N/A
CONTACT: FRIEND
    First Name: JIHAD
    Last Name: FAIR
    Number: N/A
    Address: 49 AMBER LN
```

Typing `delcontact` in my program and then FRIEND will remove the FRIEND contact from the `db`.

```
Type a command, help or quit to exit the program.
debug()
Activating DEBUG Function.

{'DEV': {'Last Name': 'MARTIN', 'First Name': 'FELIX', 'Number': 'N/A', 'Address': 'N/A'}, 'FRIEND': {'Last Name': 'FAIR', 'First Name': 'JIHAD', 'Number': 'N/A', 'Address': '49 AMBER LN'}}
Type a command, help or quit to exit the program.
delcontact
What contact shall you delete?
friend
Type a command, help or quit to exit the program.
debug()
Activating DEBUG Function.

{'DEV': {'Last Name': 'MARTIN', 'First Name': 'FELIX', 'Number': 'N/A', 'Address': 'N/A'}}
Type a command, help or quit to exit the program.
```

Finally, I type `writefile`. It successfully overwrites the file with the up-to-date `db`. However, it leaves a empty space at the end of the file. Because of this, next time they start the program, it gives the error that I spoke of earlier:

```
Contact Manager - Felix Martin V2.8.1
LOADING . . .
LOADED!
Type a command, help or quit to exit the program.
debug()
Activating DEBUG Function.

{'DEV': {'First Name': 'FELIX', 'Address': 'N/A', 'Number': 'N/A', 'Last Name': 'MARTIN'}}
Type a command, help or quit to exit the program.
addcontact
What is the contacts reference name?
friend
What is the contacts first name?
jihad
What is the contacts last name?
fair
What is the contacts (cell/main/home/etc) number?
n/a
What is the contacts address?
49 amber ln
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/personal/contactManager.py", line 235, in <module>
    App()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/personal/contactManager.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.contact_manager(db)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/personal/contactManager.py", line 228, in contact_manager
    self.contact_manager(db)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/personal/contactManager.py", line 202, in contact_manager
    self.add_contact_to_db(db, input("What is the contacts reference name?\n").upper(), input("What is the contacts first name?\n").upper(), input("What is the contacts last name?\n").upper(), input("What is the contacts (cell/main/home/etc) number?\n").upper(), input("What is the contacts address?\n").upper())
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/personal/contactManager.py", line 114, in add_contact_to_db
    db = build_db("contacts.txt")
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/personal/contactManager.py", line 24, in build_db
    category, value = map(str.strip, line.split(":"))
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Because the `writefile` function from the last run left a blank space.

How can I get rid of any blank lines within my file?

## [GitHub](https://github.com/TheGamingHideout/python-contact-manager)

Comment: Please read and follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Often, preparing these courtesies will show the problem before you get to posting.  This posting contains far too much code unrelated to the problem.

Comment: @Prune is correct here. The output and code you show leave a lot of places for errors. The code you do not show such as the code that will `read_contact` is a possible source of error. Since this function is formatting the dict to write to the file. Have you looked at the file after writing the new db? From the code you show that created the DEV contact when there is no file it looks you you may accidentally put the `CONTACT:FRIEND` line on the end of the 'ADDRESS' field of the DEV contact. It is impossible to tell for sure since the code that the output suggests the error is in is missing.

Comment: @Ajay I left the code that's related to the `.txt` file, which is why for full-debugging I left the GitHub link with the whole program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it would be a good idea to put the bit of code that was added to fix the issue in an option that way if someone clones the repo to look at it they can reproduce the issue exactly as you described in the question! It is also a good idea to either tag the question as python3 or say that you are using python3 somewhere so that if someone tries to run it it will run.

Anyway here is what I got.

The `read_contact` function in your source (ln 144) defines the `formatting` string for the `write_bd_to_file` function Like this"

```
    def read_contact(self, db,contact_name):
        formatting = """\
CONTACT: {contact},
    First Name: {First Name},
    ... and so on
    Address: {}
"""
```

This is going to insert a newline after `address: {contact}` when the db gets written after the new contact is added the app re-initializes itself from the file. When It goes back to read the file there is a blank line after DEV because of this code. This string is the same as writing:

```
formatting="CONTACT:{contact},\n\tFirst Name:{first name},\n ...Address:{Address}\n"
```

You escaped the leading newline, but not the trailing one. You can fix this by removing the newline from the end:

```
"""\
CONTACT: {contact},
    First Name: {First Name},
    ... and so on
    Address: {}\
"""
```

or just:

```
"""CONTACT: {contact},
    First Name: {First Name},
    ... and so on
    Address: {}"""
```

In response to your comment:

I see what you are talking about. I think that this requires you to address a slight design issue. In some cases contacts are written to the file using the formatting string in `read_contact` However in other places they are written to the file using code like this.

```
outf.write('\n CONTACT:' +contact_info['contact'])
outf.write('\n     First Name: ' +contact_info['First Name'])
...
```

You should really have all of your writing to the file handled by one function. I would suggest editing the function `read_contact` to take a dictionary like `contact_info` not a `db`. The part of the function that parses the `db` and `contact_name` arguments can be separated into another function that then hands its `contact_info` dict to the function that returns the formatted string.

```
def format_contact_info(self contact_info):
    formatting = """CONTACT:{contact}
"First Name: {First Name}
"Last Name: {Last Name}
"Number: {Number}
"Address: {Address}"""

     return formatting.format(**contact_info)
```

Then the `add_contact_to_db` function

```
       with open('contacts.txt', 'a+') as f:
        #write the data **Replace this block with**
        #f.write("\nCONTACT: " + contact_info['contact'])
        #f.write("\n    First Name: " + contact_info['First Name'])
        #f.write("\n    Last Name: " + contact_info['Last Name'])
        #f.write("\n    Number: " + contact_info['Number'])
        #f.write("\n    Address: " + contact_info['Address'])
        #rebuild the db
        f.write("\n"+self.format_contact_info(contact_info))
    db = build_db("contacts.txt")
```

And in `write_db_to_file`

```
for contact_name in db:
    this_contact = self.extract(contact_name.upper(), db) 
    outf.write(self.format_contact_info(this_contact))
    outf.write('\n')
```

and the `extract` function is doing the work of the beginning sections of the old `read_contact` function

```
def extract(self, contact_name, db):
    contact_name = contact_name.upper()
    contact_info = db.get(contact_name)
    contact_info['contact'] = contact_name 
    return contact_info
```

Comment: Ill vote it up, but both your solutions create 1 big contact like so: `CONTACT: DEV
    First Name: FELIX
    Last Name: MARTIN
    Number: N/A
    Address: N/ACONTACT: MOM
    First Name: SANDY
    Last Name: BRENNEMAN
    Number: (319)-631-8708
    Address: 3550 VISTA PARK DRCONTACT: FRIEND
    First Name: JIHAD
    Last Name: FAIR
    Number: N/A
    Address: 49 AMBER LN` If you can fix this, I'll accept as an answer.

Comment: `"""
CONTACT: {contact}
    First Name: {First Name}
    Last Name: {Last Name}
    Number: {Number}
    Address: {Address}\
"""` this solution creates a inverse problem. Now the line is at the very beginning.

Comment: @TheGamingHideout see my edits above My copy of your code including the changes I have made runs perfectly. I can start with no `contacts.txt` run it to make one, run it again `addcontact` twice, `writefile` and then quit. Open it again, `addcontact` and `writefile` all with no errors.

Comment: @TheGamingHideout I don't want you to get in trouble if this is for a class or something, but If this is just you working, learning, whatever; I can open a pull request on github and you can compare my changes to see what I have changed more clearly than my explanation above.

Comment: Ill accept this as an answer, but my `remove_contact_from_db` still creates that extra line, and I can't seem to figure it out. Further assistance with that will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Of course I haven't tested that function actually, but we can move this discussion over to the pull request since its rapidly moving even further way from the scope of SO questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91195/discussion-between-the-gaming-hideout-and-ajay).